# exitBlockOnFail or clear session to control a flow

Tags: gatling

Simplified my scenario to confirm the usage.

I am storing itemId in session to use in further execution. I have added doIf so that further execution happens only if itemId was present.

A user will keep cycle through the scenario until the duration in minutes.

If in first execution itemId was stored in session but in second execution POST call fails to generate itemId. I still get the itemId in session.

My expectation is to have clear session for each cycle of scenario for the same user. I tried session.reset but I get this error `java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: timestamp.`

I can use exitBlockOnFail() and change my POST to fail by adding a check if itemId is not present. Is this the recommended approach?

Is there any option? Am I using this correctly?

```
val testScenario = scenario("Test scenario").during(durationInMinutes) {
    exec(http("Create")
            .post("/items")
                .body(StringBody(session => write(Item(1, "Item name"))(DefaultFormats))).asJSON
                    .check(status.is(201), header("Location")
                        .transform(extractId(".*/items/(.*)".r, _))
                            .saveAs("itemId")))
    .doIf(_.contains("itemId")) {
        // do something with the itemId
    }
}

setUp(testScenario.inject(atOnceUsers(10)))
        .pauses(constantPauses)
            .protocols(httpProtocol)
                .assertions(global.failedRequests.count.is(0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing implicit feature available in gatling to achieve this.

I have to explicitly remove the attributes from session at the end of each run like this i.e. at the end of the scenario -

```
session.removeAll("itemId", "customerId")
```